# Adding illegal null derefernce to xv6

Tags: xv6

I am attempting to make dereferencing null pointers illegal in my build of xv6. In order to accomplish this, I have made the following changes to the source code:

changed `sz = 0` to `sz = PGSIZE` on exec.c:42

changed `i = 0` to `i = PGSIZE` in the function copyuvm() on vm.c:327

added `i == 0` to the or conditional in function agrptr() on syscall.c:66

set entrypoint for user code 0x1000 in Makefile:149&156

When I attempt to run xv6 in qemu with these modifications, I get the warning "panic: loaduvm: address should exist" When I run the debugger, this happens the first time loaduvm() is called by the first instance of exec(). If anyone has any pointers as to what I am missing, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `-Ttext 0x1000` in `_forktest` target of Makefile